# SSL certificate for nginx as a reverse proxy

Tags: nginx

I purchased a certificate from goDady, downloaded the zip file, unzipped it and found 2 files both with .crt extension. 
How ever the command I used to initiate the process as instructed by them created 2 files a example.key and example.csr in the current directory.

In my nginx.conf I need to reference a key and a crt files.
the key file is obvious since it is the only one. but the .crt is not since there are two. 
Which do I need to reference in the nginx.conf and why there are two .crt files from the zipped file?

Here is what I choose to put in the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.conf`

```
ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/4a55aakdkd9n8ne8e.crt;
ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/example.key;
```

**edit**
After the answer, below is what I did

```
ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/4a55aakdkd9n8ne8e.crt;
ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/example.key;
ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
```

I hope this is what drookie meant.

Comment: One file, two (or more) certificates inside.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains . Basically, do "cat 4a55aakdkd9n8ne8e.cat gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt > example.com.chained.crt" and then insert *just one* ssl_certificate line pointing to example.com.chained.crt. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of them is the certificate for the CN you requested and the other is the intermediate certificate to complete the certificate [chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_trust). You should put them in the file pointed by the `ssl_certificate` in the [following order](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate):

> ***ssl_certificate*** file;
>
> Specifies a file with the certificate in the PEM format for the given virtual server. If intermediate certificates should be specified in addition to a primary certificate, they should be specified in the same file in the following order: the primary certificate comes first, then the intermediate certificates.

I would also recommend to test your SSL configuration with [Qualys SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/), sort of industry standard nowadays.

Comment: Not sure which is the primary and which is the intermediate, I placed them as follows     ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/4a55aakdkd9n8ne8e.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/example.key;
    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

Comment: you could check the certificate contents with `openssl x509 -in <file> -text -noout`.

Comment: that command produces some info and some key numbers and the like. not sure that to check for though.

Comment: You need to learn how to read the certificate in a text form.

Comment: Check the *Subject* field and see what the *CN* value is. But to be honest, you lack the basic knowledge about the x509 to be involved in the SSL setups. May be you need to hand over this to someone else, or to hire a freelancer.